# Updating matrix values with multiple conditions in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function

I have pp:

```
x = [1 2 5; 1 3 nan; 1 3 4]
```

I am tryng to write a function that will update values in pp(1:n,3) with multiple conditions:

If x(p,3) is NaN, AND pp(p,2) is 3 AND the x(p-1,1) is the same as x(p,1),

then set x(p,3) = x(p-1,3).

Basically I want to set nan values in the third column to the value in the previous row if the value in the previous column is 3 and the value in the first column is the same as the previous row.

My code:

```
function x = Updatevalue(x)
[rows]=size(x, 1); 
for p=2:rows
    if (isnan(x(x(p,3)))) && (x(x(p,2) == 3)) && (x(x(p,1)) == x(x(p-1,1))) 
       x(x(p,3)) = x(x(p-1,3)); 
    end
end
```

Which gives me error:

Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

```
Error in Updatevalue (line 4)
if (isnan(x(x(p,3)))) && (x(x(p,2) == 3)) && (x(x(p,1)) == x(x(p-1,1)))
```

I get the same error when I change && to &. I am still very new to MATLAB, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this, your `isnan(x(x(p,3)))` and `x(x(p,3))=` are both wrong. If `x(p,3)` is a `NaN`, you're trying to do `x(NaN)`.

```
[rows]=size(x, 1); 
for p=2:rows
    if (isnan(x(p,3))) && (x(p,2) == 3) && (x(p,1) == x(p-1,1)) 
      x(p,3) = x(p-1,3); 
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I edited your code for my solution. I took your advice and removed the (x(x())).  I guess I got a bit carried away with encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

Because when `p=1` `x(p-1,1)` does not exist. Just change the for loop to start at 2, as your conditions can not happen when `p==1` anyways.

Comment: Good catch Ander; I change my for to read 'for p=2:rows'. (I will also edit the original post).  However, I am still getting the same error.  I wonder is there an encapsulation / logical issue or, beyond isnan(), should I user true() on the second and third conditions?

Comment: Is the new error in the next line (i.e. `x(x(p,3)) = x(x(p-1,3)); `)? If so, check the logic of the indexing of the left-hand side of the assignment...

Comment: No, I still get the same error. I think Ander saved me from an error I would have encountered in next step of debugging.  I am still getting an error with my conditions on line 4.